# Building on Heroku -avoiding global dependencies

Tags: node.js, heroku

[According to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies) I should avoid global dependencies when asking Heroku to build my project. But I still want Bower and Grunt on the command line.

My question is: how then should I be running these tools?

Rather than installing them with `npm install -g`, should I be adding paths from `node_modules` to `PATH`, or the like? (Ubuntu)

If Grunt/Bower are installed globally on development machines -say when someone new starts on the project -then presumably `npm install -g grunt-cli` might give a different Grunt version to what's in `package.json`. Hence what Heroku runs and what developers run might accidentally differ.

(Or is that unlikely to be a problem?)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to keep everything local, with npm install --save.
That way you can align versions for everyone in the team simply by tweaking the package.json file.

If you only need Bower and Grunt etc. to be available in your dev environments, then install them with npm install --save-dev. This will cause them to be saved in a devDependencies section in your package.json. Dependencies referenced therein will not get distributed to production (e.g. Heroku), but will be available in all your dev environments.

If you really do need Bower and Grunt etc. to be available on Heroku, then install them with npm install --save.

At any rate, npm should automatically save symbolic links to your executables (e.g. grunt-cli) in directory node_modules/.bin, and should take care of adding node_modules/.bin to your PATH, so you don't have to worry about that.